# Table data import in webpage using python possible?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

Please see the image below. I want to create a dynamic web page (using html, css and javascript) where the tables get values through a python script. Please tell me if this is possible? (Thorugh javascript, I have functionality that when I click a certain table name, data corresponding to that table only is displayed on right hand side.)

[image]

Comment: I just want to know whether its possible or not. Regarding code, I dont think it will be of any use.

Comment: @Era I have provided the answer for how I am doing it. Thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with `mako` template.

Just use `from mako.template import Template`.

Now, using the Template functionality, you can do this. Here, make a html template having python in it. 
Eg. 
`% for COMPNAME in tpdob.scalar_not_adv:
    <tr>
        <td>${COMPNAME}</td>
    </tr>
% endfor`
Then create a html webpage using `Template` itself for showing the output.